# Description Box using "onmouseover"

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I am playing with the `onmouseover` event in javascript

I would like a little box to pop up and remain up until there is no `onmouseover` anymore

I think it's called a description box, but I am not sure.

How do I get a little box to pop up with custom text when I put my mouse over certain text, and disappear once I move the mouse to a different object..?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming `popup` is the ID of your "description box":

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent"> <!-- This is the main container, to mouse over -->
<div id="popup" style="display: none">description text here</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var e = document.getElementById('parent');
e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}
e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Alternatively you can get rid of JavaScript entirely and do it just with CSS:

**CSS**

```
#parent #popup {
  display: none;
}

#parent:hover #popup {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: also .popup ==> #popup

Comment: I found the CSS solution did not work unless the `style="display: none"` is removed from the `div`

Answer (score 28):

Although not necessarily a JavaScript solution, there is also a "title" global tag attribute that may be helpful.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559467/description-box-on-mouseover" title="This is a title.">Mouseover me</a>
```

[Mouseover me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559467/description-box-on-mouseover)

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question as asked, it removes the need for javascript to solve the problem implied by the question. Very nice. +1

Comment: Nothing happened when I did a mouseover. I guess this  method is not as reliable as the CSS one. But it could just be my browser too. Using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m

Comment: @Iancel0t it does work, you have to wait a second before the title comes up.

Comment: While this is a nice "outside the box" solution, I would suggest reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) before implementing it in this way.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I made a simple two liner script for this, Its small and does what u want.

Check it
http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/

Its a jquery solution :D

Comment: This solution is not optimal if I am trying to put links and stuff the user needs to click since the placement of the box is independent from the triggering element.
This shall illustrate the problem (that also I have)
http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/6078/

Comment: 20 min later with the jsfiddle tool I was able to find a solution: add property "position: relative;" to parent (".tiptext") and set "left"-property for the child (".decription") to any value, (e.g. "0px"), like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/6079/

Answer (score 3):

This an old question but for people still looking. In JS you can now use the `title` property.

```
button.title = ("Popup text here");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try doing this with jQuery's [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event handler system, it makes it easy to show a div with the tooltip when the mouse is over the text, and hide it once it's gone.

Here's a simple example.

HTML:

```
​<p id="testText">Some Text</p>
<div id="tooltip">Tooltip Hint Text</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Basic CSS:

```
​#​tooltip {
display:none;
border:1px solid #F00;
width:150px;
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$("#testText").hover(
   function(e){
       $("#tooltip").show();
   },
   function(e){
       $("#tooltip").hide();
  });​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS Tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) allows you to format the popup as you like as any `div` section! And no Javascript needed.