# How to create hoverover popups in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been searching for a way to implement a hover-over popup with no luck.  Because it is used on so many sites I thought it would be easy to find instructions, but I am wondering if I am missing something basic.  I have looked at qTips2 and a few others, but these seem like way more than I need.

I have a Rails 3.1 app and want to display more details when a user hovers over a line in a table.  Is this something built into Rails that I am missing, or do I need an add-on?

I sure would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: That would be a simple hovering div.

Comment: This isn't a Rails question, but rather a CSS or JavaScript question.

Comment: Ha! javascript and css tags were added before I could get to it.

Comment: We'll need a bit more explanation: 1) what do you mean with 'hover-over popup' (just the default browser tooltip, a styleable multiline div,...?) 2) what does your table html look like, and what items should trigger the mouseover?

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559467/description-box-using-onmouseover, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359193/plain-javascript-tooltip or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683620/how-to-display-pop-up-text-on-mouse-hover. The currently shown duplicate has been deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use some CSS and Javascript!

Here's an example you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/cdpZg/

Copying it here, just in case.

HTML:

```
<div id='user'>I am a user. Move your mouse over me</div>
<div id='popup'>Extended info about a user</div>
<div>I a piece of useless information. No use hovering over me.</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user').hover(function() {
        $('#popup').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#popup').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sergi,
For the benefit of anyone else... To get this to work in my Rails 3.1 app, I had to surrond the Javascript with

`$(document).ready(function(){ 
"javascript goes here"
});`

Comment: @SteveO7 yeah, that's kinda basic stuff. I'll update my answer, just in case :-)

Comment: Sometimes that basic stuff can cost you a lot of time!  Thanks again

Comment: Good luck with your project :-)

Answer (score 7):

Just set the title on your link like this

```
<a title="Some text that will show up when I hover over this link">My link</a>
```

Comment: I had no idea it was that simple... I've lead a sheltered desktop life and just getting into Rails development.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveO7 no problem, if it did work out for you please mark your question as answered for future reference, glad I can help

Comment: Bassam, Is there a way to do this on a non link?  What I want to  use it on is a "<td>" in a table.

Comment: @SteveO7 yes you should be able to, here is a link where you can read more about it, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp

Comment: Any HTML Tag like <div title="this is what shows on hover">Some Text </div>