# Select field , give option on link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, dropdown

```
<select class="form-control filter" id="filter" >
    <option value="<%=  profile_path(@profile)%>" > <%= link_to "Weekly", profile_path(@profile), class: 'form-control'%> </option>
    <option <%= params[:daily] ? "selected" : "" %> value="<%= profile_path(@profile,:daily => "true")%>"> <%= link_to "Daily", profile_path(@profile,:daily => "true"), class: 'form-control' %></option>
</select>
```

I want to give link to option field of select. It doesnot work. ANy other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a link inside an option tag is a very bad idea since its invalid HTML. In fact `<option>` tags cannot contain any other elements. [The permitted contents are "Text, possibly with escaped characters (like é)."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

```html
<select>
  <option>I just broke the internets <a href="#">click me</a></option>
</select>
```

The link won't be clickable as the browser will most likely just ignore the `<a>` tag.

What you most likely actually want to is create a form that sends GET requests:

```
<%= form_with(url: profile_path, method: :get) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :daily %>
  <%= form.select :daily, ["true", "false"], class: 'instant-submit' %>
  <%= f.submit "View profiles" %>
<% end %>
```

If you want the form to submit as soon as the user changes the select you need to use JavaScript to add a change event handler.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.instant-submit');
elements.forEach((element) =>{
  element.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    event.target.form.requestSubmit();
  });
});
```

Or you could just use actual links instead of a form and style them to get the desired user interface.

Comment: How do I handle for selected? If params daily then keep in selected else other?

Comment: I would just use a checkbox instead of a select in the first place. If you use a "normal" checkbox and not the rails helper the parameters is not added to the query string if it's not checked.

Comment: I actually need the dropdown. That is why, I am not able to keep the selected based on params

Comment: This code doesnot work on safari why ?

Comment: Not sure. Thats a very standard event handler.. It could also be an issue if you don't wrap the code in callback that fires when the DOM is ready. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `link_to` is good inside option tag since as soon the user click the option to select it will be redirect to specified path which you may not want.

Try this:

```rb
options = [
  [
    "Weekly",
    profile_path(@profile)
  ],
  [
    "Daily",
    profile_path(@profile, :daily => "true")
  ]
]

<%= select_tag :filter, options_for_select(options, "Daily") %>
```

Sample Output:

```html
<select id="filter">
  <option value="/profile/1">Weekly</option>
  <option value="/profile/2&daily=true">Daily</option>
</select>
```

If you want to add `tooltip` in option you can either use [`title`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag) or create it using [`css`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp) or [`javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359193/plain-javascript-tooltip)

#### Example using [`title`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249591/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-on-an-html-option-tag)

```
options = [
  [
    "Weekly",
    profile_path(@profile),
    { :title => profile_path(@profile) }
  ],
  [
    "Daily",
    profile_path(@profile, :daily => "true"),
    { :title => profile_path(@profile, :daily => "true") }
  ]
]

<%= select_tag :filter, options_for_select(options, "Daily") %>
```

Sample Output:

```html
<select id="filter">
  <option title="/profile/1" value="/profile/1">Weekly</option>
  <option title="/profile/2&daily=true" value="/profile/2&daily=true">Daily</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 1. Browsers won't actually even render the link. 2. This is not a correct use of the `title` attribute and what are you even trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: @max since the question included link inside option which is not possible as you pointed out i though he want to show tooltip which is why he is using the link inside option.

Comment: You linked to a 12 year old question. `title` does nothing on option tags in modern browsers.