# Why does onclick not fire for HTML button inside tooltip window?

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

What is wrong with the following piece of HTML+JavaScript? The `alert()` in `onclick` apparently never gets called for a button inside a tooltip window.

I've tried this with several browsers, e.g. Firefox 33.1. Outside the context of a tooltip  (i.e. by removing `class="tooltip"` from the sample) it functions. The tooltip relies on CSS alone in a way that is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559467/description-box-on-mouseover).

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <style type="text/css">

    .cell {
      position:relative;
    }

    .tooltip {
      position:absolute;
      left:10px;
      top:10px;
      background-color:gray;
      z-index:100;
      width:200px;
    }

    .cell:active .tooltip { visibility:hidden !important; }
    .cell:hover .tooltip  { visibility:visible; }
    .tooltip              { visibility:hidden; }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell">
          CELL
          <div class="tooltip">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>KEY</td>
                <td>VALUE</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <form>
              <button type="button" onclick="alert('TEST');">EDIT</button>
            </form>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no way the alert wouldn't work just because some css was applied. there must be OTHER javascript preventing it.

Comment: @MarcB The only JavaScript in this example is the `alert('TEST')` in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. missed the onclick attribute in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exemple works fine in IE8 browser.

---

For FF browser and chrome
Please comment this style

```
.cell:active .tooltip { visibility:hidden !important; }
```

Comment: Oh common this cannot be an answer you ought to post this on comment.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you click the button the `hover` class is lost and the button disappears. If you were to use a `mouseover` instead of click it would work:

```
          <button type="button" onMouseOver="alert('TEST');">EDIT</button>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yt9kvngr/

Comment: +1 If I click anywhere else in the tooltip, the `hover` class apparently survives. Is this difference explained somewhere in the relevant standards? Also, do know another way for detecting a click on the button (perhaps working from the fact that `onmouseover` does work)?

Comment: you can set the visibility via javascript and handle the showing/hiding there: http://jsfiddle.net/yt9kvngr/1/ I just used jQuery for a quick answer, you could of course always solve this with vanilla javascript

Comment: I see: giving up on the CSS-only tooltip could be an option.