# Onmouseover for a Button to show a description box

Tags: javascript, html, css, multimedia

I would like a little text box to pop up and remain up until there is no onmouseover for that button anymore.

How do I get a little box to pop up with custom text when I put my mouse over a button and disappear once I move the mouse  ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: This question was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559467/description-box-using-onmouseover/26160910#26160910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript..(next time make an attempt :D)

```js
function in_out(e){
if(e.type=='mouseover'){
 document.getElementById('textbox').style.display='inline';
  }
else if(e.type=='mouseout'){
 document.getElementById('textbox').style.display='none';
 }
}


document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mouseover',in_out,false)
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mouseout',in_out,false)
```

```css
#textbox {
  width:100px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='textbox'>
<br>
<button id='button'>
hover here
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without javascript just html markeup and css

```
  <a href="#" class="popup">
    Tooltip
    <span>
        <strong>Most Light-weight Tooltip</strong><br />
        This is the easy-to-use Tooltip driven purely by CSS.
    </span>
</a>
</div>
```

make the span element `display:none` and onhover make it visible see my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fqybs98b/)