# Pop up message on mouseover div

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

Trying to get a simple popup to appear on `mouseover` a `div` I followed the answer [Description Box using "onmouseover"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559467/description-box-on-mouseover) but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
    .parent .popup {
      display: none;
    }
    .parent:hover .popup {
      display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById('#parent');
    e.onmouseover = function() {
      document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
    }
    e.onmouseout = function() {
      document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>


<div id="parent">
    This is the main container.
    <div id="popup" style="display: none">some text here</div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The comment on the accepted answer there refers to the problem, you need to be using ID selectors not class ones. Also the answer there tells you don't need the JS if you use the CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems. You are referencing classes in the CSS (. is class and # is id) second, you don't need to overload the CSS display none style. Finally, you don't need the JavaScript in this case.

See the working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
    #parent #popup {
      display: none;
    }
    #parent:hover #popup {
      display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div id="parent">
    This is the main container.
    <div id="popup">some text here</div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `title="Some popup text"` inside the html tag e.g...

```html
<button class="toolbar-item-fontcolour" 
        title="Font colour"  
        id="btnFontColour" 
        @onclick="ShowColourSelectorFont">A</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the popup is outside (not inside the parent), then:

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
}

#sibling:hover+#popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sibling">
  This is the main container.
</div>
<div id="popup">some text here</div>
```