# after one word is clicked then popup explains it, changes text color to red onmouseover, then changes color back to black onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, popup

I use this script below to change the color for every single word when mouse over that word, and changes back to black when mouse out of that word, and works great. Also, If user want to hear the pronunciation then can click on the word to play the sound, which works great.

There are huge number of words on the text, and for every single word different explanations/popups.

But where im stuck is that i like to add popup over every word onmouseover, and to show explanation for that word only.

I like how it works on html `<p title="Explanation">word-1</p>` but using js i found difficult to implement.
Also i found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353532/pop-up-message-on-mouseover-div) using css which i like it, but difficult to combine with js.

```
<script>
   function playAudio(url) {
   new Audio(url).play();
 }
</script>
```

```
<p>
<font size="6" style="font-weight:bold;" onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio-1.mp3')">first-word</font>
        
<font size="6" style="font-weight:bold;" onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio-2.mp3')">second-word</font>
                
<font size="6" style="font-weight:bold;" onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="playAudio('audio-3.mp3')">third-word</font>
</p>
```

Comment: I think before we get into the nitty gritty of exactly how to structure your HTML (it is using deprecated features) or worrying about creating a huge number of event listeners and audio elements, it would be useful to learn more about how the info about each word is currently stored/created. Is there a database or something, some sort of dictionary, etc.

Comment: Yes, its some kind of dictionary. Learning to read, translation of every word and pronunciation of it.
Database on csv format is converted to html like static page. Because of that, when every word is done on the way how is described above, taking into account that there are huge number of words, is very important the web page to be responsive without lags on client pc, including the requests from server. That is why i decided on this way, to be simple to use, and practical. That is why im forced to use the structure of html on this way, and without including external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are trying to accomplish something like this. I you are using Twitter Bootstrap its simple(rather than creating your own popups)

Here is a sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-oc9+XSs1H243/FRN9Rw62Fn8EtxjEYWHXRvjS43YtueEewbS6ObfXcJNyohjHqVKFPoXXUxwc+q1K7Dee6vv9g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<style>
.para font{position:relative; cursor:pointer}
.para font:hover{color:red;}
</style>
<body>

<p class="para">
    <font size="6" data-word="First Word" data-audio="https://pagalnew.com/mp3-songs/english-mp3-songs/breaking-the-rules-jubin-nautiyal-128-kbps-sound.mp3" data-content="Lorem Ipsum">first-word</font>
    <font size="6" data-word="Second Word" data-audio="https://naijamusics.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Imagine-Dragons-Believer.mp3" data-content="Lorem Ipsum 2">second-word</font>           
    <font size="6" data-word="Third Word" data-audio="https://www.fcsongs.com/uploads/audio/Ricky%20Martin%20-%20The%20Cup%20Of%20Life.mp3" data-content="Lorem Ipsum 3">third-word</font>
</p>

<div class="modal" id="AudioPlayer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <audio id="player" controls style="width:100%">
          <source id="audioSrc" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-iceXjjbmB2rwoX93Ka6HAHP+B76IY1z0o3h+N1PeDtRSsyeetU3/0QKJqGyPJcX63zysNehggFwMC/bi7dvMig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".para font").popover({
        trigger : 'hover',
        placement : 'auto',
        boundary : "viewport"
    });
    
    $('.para font').on("click",function(){
        var title = $(this).data("word");
        var audioURL = $(this).data("audio");
        $("#AudioPlayer .modal-title").html(title);
        $("#AudioPlayer").modal();
        var audio = $("#player");
        $("#player #audioSrc").attr('src',audioURL);
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
    });
    
    $('#AudioPlayer').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('audio').each(function(){
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
      }); 
    })
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sobinmanuel/v58Lkh3z/2/)